# How can I cross the Haunted Wasteland if I can't see well enough?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I'm playing through Ocarina of Time on the Wii (Virtual Console), and due to eyesight issues (I've got keratoconus, which results in light trails on bright images, causing troubles with similarly contrasted pictures), I'm having troubles navigating through the Haunted Wasteland to get to the Spirit Temple, having attempted it nearly 30 times.

I've read a few guides and watched a few walkthrough videos, but the guides just say "follow the flags", while the videos just waltz on through like it's nothing. I've also opened up my phone camera and inverted the colours to try and use it as a "lens of truth" of sorts, but due to Android's "smart colour inversion", the orange of the desert is still orange, and not blue like I'd expect. I've even used a capture card to watch (and invert) the game on my PC, but that still didn't work.

Is there an easier way to get through (e.g. "use the lens of truth", "look which way the wind is blowing" or "walk 45 degrees from the merchant sign, then at the next flag, walk turn to face the wind and walk straight")?

Comment: I have a similar visual impairment and feel your pain about old video games not being great about accessibility. Glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I eventually figured out a way to get through after exhausting all my other options.

To navigate the wasteland, I played the Song of Storms a few times. The resulting lightning strikes lit the scene up enough for me to locate the next flag and walk through. The next few parts were relatively easy.

This is why I'm thankful for newer games like The Last of Us 2, which caters to the vision impaired!

Answer (score 3):

As [you previously suggested](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/379695/73976) the Song of Storms can be used to Light up the surrounding area so that you can see properly.

The primary way this is meant to be done, is to use the Eye of Truth to reveal a Poe that guides you through the wasteland. I can't say for sure, but I don't think this does anything to improve the background - it simply makes the Poe itself visible (the Eye of Truth usually does have a purple overlay, allowing you to aim the "viewing circle", but I have personally had issues with this in some Virtual Consoles).

Alternatively, there is [this map](https://ootmap.com/#13/-0.1392/0.1351), which does show the map, posts and path you need to take, though it might be a little difficult to follow. At the very least you might be able to count the posts, and try and deduce the angles you need to move in order to follow the path properly.

Comment: This question is about the *first* half of the maze, the "follow the flags" part. The Poe guide is for the *second* half.

Comment: Wish I'd found this map earlier, because it was exactly what I was after. I can zoom in and out, and even go from side view to top down which helps immensely. Once I got past the flags half, the Poe half was dead simple and I was relieved I could go on.